# Where is R installed in Fedora?

Tags: linux, r, fedora, yum

I installed `R` using `yum`, by

```
sudo yum install R
```

and this was successful. When I type

```
yum list R
```

I get:

```
Installed Packages
R.x86_64                                                                 3.2.0-2.fc20
```

However, when I type `R` at the prompt, I get:

```
bash: R: command not found...
```

Where was `R` installed and how can I use it?

RStudio can't find an installation either!

Comment: What is the output of `type R`?

Comment: What does `rpm -V R` output? What does `declare -p PATH` output? What does `rpm -ql R | grep /bin/` output?

Comment: `declare -p PATH` outputs
`declare -x PATH="/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/home/carmensandoval/Software/D3E"`

Comment: `type R` returns`bash: type: R: not found`

Comment: `rpm -V R` and `rpm -ql R | grep /bin/` return nothing.

Comment: HI everyone, thanks for your help with this. I unfortunately still can't get R to work. Is there anything else you would suggest trying? Thanks!

Comment: `R` is a metapackage (that is, a package just requiring a complete set of other packages to be installed together). The R executable bits are delivered in the `R-core` rpm package, and the R executable should be available at `/usr//bin/R`.

Answer (score 3):

`R` is a metapackage (that is, a package just requiring a complete set of other packages to be installed together). The R executable bits are delivered in the `R-core` rpm package, and the R executable should be available at `/usr/bin/R`.

Make sure R-core is installed with:

```
yum install R-core
```

or try:

```
yum reinstall R
```

to see if the metapackage brings in the dependencies correctly.